# How to conditionally format values from a table displayed with a numeric array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a table that gathers some data from a MySQL table. For some reason, it only displayed the contents as columns once I used `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` but now I am stuck, as no JS or PHP function seems to work conditionally formatting the results of the column. Those results range where everything between 52 and 120 should be in red.

```
$sql = "SELECT mac_address,upstream,downstream_snr,downstream,uptime from modems where rpi_serial='$rpi'";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$nRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if ($nRows > 0) {
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="modems">
              <tr><th class="col-md-5ths" id="MC">Mac</th><th class="col-md-5ths">Upstream</th>
              <th class="col-md-5ths id="DWS">Downstream SNR</th><th class="col-md-5ths" id="DW">Downstream</th>
              <th class="col-md-5ths">Uptime</th></tr>';
    // Output data of each row    
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {

        echo "<tr><td  style=\"$colour\">".$row["0"]."</td><td>".$row["1"]."</td><td>".$row["2"]."</td><td>".$row["3"]."</td><td>".$row["4"]."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `$nRows` is an array, not a number. `if ($nRows > 0)` makes no sense. To get the number of rows use `$nRows = $stmt->rowCount();`. But this only works with some databases (e.g. MySQL).

Comment: Try $nRows = $stmt->rowCount();

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Thanks for the advise!, sorry, still learning over here....@GrumpyCrouton have heard something similar before, do you guys happen to know of a good tutorial for solving security issues?, thanks again

Comment: _"as no JS or PHP function seems to work conditionally formatting the results of the column"_ - I don't see any such attempts in the code you have shown. When asking here, please do not just tell us that you "tried something, didn't work" - but _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: _"Those results range where everything between 52 and 120 should be in red."_ - _what_ exactly should be between those boundaries? Which field/column are you even referring to here?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments above, do this 2 loops - rows and fields.

```php
// output data of each row
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($row); $i++) {
        $value = $row[$i];
        $colour = ($value >= 52 && $value <= 120) ? "red" : "green";
        echo "<td style=\"color:$colour\">" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, while I can see the logic on this, unfortunately didn't manage to get it to work, broke the code, such a pity, would have been a great solution